# jquery call function contextually

Tags: jquery

If you use jQuery this code should be self-explanatory:

```
//fade the show-data class in or out of view
if($(this).hasClass('open')){
    $(obj).find('.show-data').hide(250);    
}else{
    $(obj).find('.show-data').show(250);
}
```

what I'm wondering if there's some way to do this in fewer lines as follows:

```
$(obj).find('.show-data').fn[$(this).hasClass('open') ? 'hide' : 'show'](250);
```

Thanks

Comment: You can, as @dystroy's answer shows. A better question is whether you _should_. Is that kind of code really clearer?

Comment: It's too bad the version of `.toggle()` that takes a `showOrHide` parameter doesn't also allow a duration.

Comment: thanks for both of your replies, as you can see i was "close" with .fn but the answer below solved that.  My criteria for doing something like this (since this is a forum) is if I believe that the logical ternary will only affect one action (in this case hide/show).  If more actions will be done, then I would go with my original curly brace logic.  Not sure why but to my brain this is actually clearer.

Comment: @SamuelFullman SO is not really a forum....

Comment: @SamuelFullman I use this construct from time to time but, as often when coding in JS, the criteria is whether I can make it clear and obvious enough. Here's an example : https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src%2Fmain-js%2Fmiaou.md.js#L20

Comment: Why do people often ask to shorten their code. Like this questions should be asked in coderview..

Comment: @dystroy line 21 of your link is the same concept.  Because it's only one operation, it's very clear to me what you've written, though you obviously could have called renderers[..] two different ways using if(condition){ .. }else{ .. }.  My philosophy is "sometimes readability of a lot of code = not making it that much more code" - and yeah C-link I will remember your advice for future.

Comment: Shortening the code makes it faster to read and thus helps readability. I find this especially important if it can make some consistent unit of code be seen at a glance. Of course the gain is void if the shortening made it harder to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this :

```
$(obj).find('.show-data')[$(this).hasClass('open') ? 'hide' : 'show'](250);
```